# React, no puedo agregar una clase para un contenedor cada vez que se escucha el evento onClick

Tags: css, reactjs, onclick

Hola que tal estoy probando por varios medios el agregar una clase `'shake-right'` en react, a un contenedor, **cada vez** que escucha el evento onClick pasado por props, de un botón `button`

La clase lo único que hace es una animación para el contenedor padre, éste es su css:

```
.shake-right{animation:shake-right 0.4s linear both} 
@keyframes shake-right{
    0%,100%{
        transform:rotate(0deg);transform-origin:100% 50%
    }
    10%{
        transform:rotate(2deg)
    }
    20%,40%,60%{
        transform:rotate(-4deg)
    }
    30%,50%,70%{
        transform:rotate(4deg)
    }
    80%{
        transform:rotate(-2deg)
    }
    90%{
        transform:rotate(2deg)
    }
}
```

La clase `shake-right` **sólo** debe colocarse en el contenedor, si el usuario al hacer click en un `button` que tiene ese mismo contenedor, éste no tiene nada de texto en un `textarea`.

En caso de tener texto al darle al `button` y lanzar el evento onClick, no se debe poner agregar la clase `shake-right`

Estoy probando por medio de `useEffect` ejecutar una función que mire si al hacer click hay texto o no en el textarea, pero no me termina de funcionar con el hook o no lo estoy planteando bien.

He probado otra solución que funciona bien, pero únicamente 1 vez, es decir, si no escribo nada, y doy click en el `button`, funciona, pero si vuelvo a dar click con el `textarea` vacío ya no funciona,  y esto ocurre porque el componente no está rerenderizando.
En caso de que escriba algo, de click, y luego vuelva a dar click con el texto vacío, al haberse renderizado sí vuelve a funcionar.
**Tengo que buscar una forma de renderizar el componente cada vez que escuche el click**, independientemente de que haya o no texto.

Para hacer lo que os comento que me funciona 1 vez este es mi código:

```
const AddNote = ({ handleAddNote }) => {
    const [noteText, setNoteText] = useState('');
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setNoteText(event.target.value);
    }
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        if (noteText.trim().length > 0){
            handleAddNote(noteText)
            if (document.querySelector('.new').classList.contains('shake-right')){
                document.querySelector('.new').classList.remove('shake-right')
            }
        }
        else{
            document.querySelector('.new').classList.add('shake-right');
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className='note new'>
            <textarea 
                id="" 
                cols="10" 
                rows="8"
                placeholder='¿Qué has aprendido hoy?'
                value={noteText}
                onChange={handleChange}>
            </textarea>
            <div className='note-footer'>
                <small>200 Remaining</small>
                <button className='save' onClick={handleClick}>Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default AddNote;
```

Fijaros como la función handleClick primero comprueba que haya texto, entonces actualiza el prop que se le pasa. Y luego mira que si existe la clase shake-right la elimine, finalmente si al hacer click no hay nada, se iría al `else` y en este caso se añadiría la clase.

Si se os ocurre algo agradezco la ayuda muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Haz la clase del contenedor una variable dentro del estado. Similar a como lo haces con `const [noteText, setNoteText] = useState('');`. De esta forma cuando actualices dicho estado, se hará nuevamente el `render` y la clase cambiará.

Comment: No lo he entendido muy bien perdona, el contenedor tendrá o no la clase en función del click que hagamos, si hago 2 clicks sin cambiar nada, solo se renderiza 1 vez.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es utilizar una variable de estado que usarás como el valor de la clase de tu `div`.

```
const AddNote = ({ handleAddNote }) => {

    const [noteText, setNoteText] = useState('');
    const [classState, setClassState] = useState('note new');

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setNoteText(event.target.value);
    }
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        if (noteText.trim().length > 0){
            handleAddNote(noteText)
            if (document.querySelector('.new').classList.contains('shake-right')){
                document.querySelector('.new').classList.remove('shake-right')
            }
            let cS = classState;
            if (cS.includes('shake-right')) {
                setClassState('note new');
            }
        } else {
            setClassState('note new shake-right');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={classState}>
            <textarea 
                id="" 
                cols="10" 
                rows="8"
                placeholder='¿Qué has aprendido hoy?'
                value={noteText}
                onChange={handleChange}>
            </textarea>
            <div className='note-footer'>
                <small>200 Remaining</small>
                <button className='save' onClick={handleClick}>Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default AddNote;
```

De esta forma, usas una variable de estado para darle un valor de clase a tu `div`.

Hice un pequeño ejemplo en CodeSanbox para que veas como funciona esto.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-brown-vh9gtg?file=/src/App.js:87-144

En mi ejemplo, cambio el color de un `div` al hacer click en un botón. Esto sucede al actualizar una `variable` de estado, de la misma forma en la que te sugiero hacer en tu código.

Comment: Hola que tal, gracias por tu tiempo, he podido comprender el código pero lo he probado y ocurre igual, funciona la primera vez, pero al volver a hacer click ya no se ejecuta la animación de la clase.

Answer (score 0):

se me ha ocurrido esta genialidad / chapucilla, me gustaría saber que opináis, desde luego me soluciona el tema, pero no sé en temas de rendimiento/performance si puede darme problemas, bugs, etc a futuros.

```
const AddNote = ({ handleAddNote }) => {
    const [noteText, setNoteText] = useState('');
    const [classState, setClassState] = useState('note new');
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        if (limiteLetras - event.target.value.length >= 0){ 
            setNoteText(event.target.value);
        }
    }
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        if (noteText.trim().length > 0){
            handleAddNote(noteText)
            setNoteText('');
            
        }
        else{
            setClassState('note new shake-right')
            setTimeout(()=>{
                setClassState('note new')
            },500)
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className={classState}>
            <textarea 
                id="" 
                cols="10" 
                rows="8"
                placeholder='¿Qué has aprendido hoy?'
                value={noteText}
                onChange={handleChange}>
            </textarea>
            <div className='note-footer'>
                <small>{limiteLetras - noteText.length} Remaining</small>
                <button className='save' onClick={handleClick}>Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default AddNote;
```

La clase shake-right es la que contiene la animación, al renderizarse el componente se le aplica y viendo las condiciones, se le aplica o no esa clase, una vez se le aplica, salta la animación.
Como me estaba funcionando solo 1 vez, y hasta que no se volviese a renderizar no se podía volver a aplicar la clase, se me ha ocurrido meterlo en un `setTimeout`

1. Primero pone la clase si el usuario ha hecho click y no hay nada escrito.
2. Segundo, en un timeout que dura nada, se le quita dicha clase, de esta forma cuando el usuario vuelva a dar click, se volverá a poner la clase de la animación, y tras unos segundos se volverá a quitar, y así en bucle hasta que el usuario decida poner algo en el textarea.